# Mat.at function throwing exception

Tags: c++, opencv

In my code, i want to access each element of Mat type matrix. Matrix is obtained as output of SIFT algorithm.

`SiftFeatureDetector detector;
detector.compute(image, keypoints, siftFeatureDescriptor);
cout<<siftFeatureDescriptor.at<double>(0,0);`

When i tried running this code, it throws exception at the siftFeatureDescriptor.at function.

When i tried changing double to int, exception is gone but it displays wrong value 1114898432 whereas the actual value is 49.

Using Mat.type i found the type of matrix is 32FC1.

Please help.

Comment: if mat.type is 32FC1 you should access it using at<float> for sure

Comment: Changing to float for all the variables used solved the issue. thanks.

Comment: I added that in my final answer. You can validate the answer so others know that your problem is solved...

Answer (score 2):

if mat.type is 32FC1 you should access it using `at<float>` for sure.

Furthermore I guess you might be mixing up "detector" and "extractor". Normally you should use them like this:

```
// initialize detector and extractor
  FeatureDetector* detector = new SiftFeatureDetector(
                                     0, // nFeatures
                                     4, // nOctaveLayers
                                     0.04, // contrastThreshold
                                     10, //edgeThreshold
                                     1.6 //sigma
                                     );
  DescriptorExtractor* extractor = new SiftDescriptorExtractor();

  // detect the keypoints
  vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
  detector->detect(img, keypoints);

  // now compute the descriptors for each keypoint
  Mat descriptors;
  extractor->compute(img, keypoints, descriptors);
```

I base the code on [this example](https://gist.github.com/thorikawa/3398619)